# LASSO with poorly conditioned predictors

Tags: least-squares, lasso

I need to solve equations of the form $Ax=b$, with $A$ a $m\times n$ matrix with $m>n$.

I am looking at the usual least squares solution $x_0=A^+b$, where $A^+$ is the pseudoinverse and at the LASSO solution $x_L$.

I have observed that when the smallest singular value of $A$ becomes very small, $x_0$ becomes wild, with very large elements. This is of course no surprise at all. What is surprising is that $x_L$ is still very well behaved.

Why is the LASSO solution almost insensitive to the ill conditioning of $A$?

EDIT: I have consulted the book "Elements of Statistical Learning", as suggested, but I could not find an explanation in there to my question. I understand why the ridge algorithm performs well when $A$ is ill conditioned: it is because the solution to ridge involves not the inverse of $A$ but the inverse of $A+\lambda$, so this regularizes the solution. I would like to get a similar understanding in the case of LASSO.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=lasso

Comment: Do you understand why ridge solution would also be insesitive to the poor conditioning of A?

Comment: When $A$ is rank defficient least squares estimation is unbiassed but has high variance.  A penalization method such as ridge or lasso sacrifices some bias for (much) less variance. I belive is easier to understand how this work in Ridge (with explicit formulas for the variance) than lasso.

Comment: @Manuel And where do you suggest I learn this?

Comment: elements of statistical learning - free pdf available

Comment: As per your edit - do you understand why inverting $A+\lambda$ regularizes the solution?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Well, $(A+\lambda)^{-1}$ is finite when $A^{-1}$ is not

Comment: There's more to it than just that; by increasing $\lambda$, the condition number (ratio of largest to smallest eigenvalues) of the matrix can be greatly reduced, so the matrix is no longer singular or "almost" singular.

Comment: This important question points out why in high dimensional situations it is usualy more productive (and certainly more interpretable) to use data reduction (unsupervised learning) methods before analyzing the outcome variable.   Such methods include sparse principal components, variable clustering followed by ordinary principal components, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you're solving $Ay = b$, you're automatically placing yourself into a normal OLS regression problem. Lasso simply does not belong to that kind of problem, which is why "the matrix being ill conditioned" has little meaning.

By solving a normal OLS, you're finding $b$ that minimizes

$RSS(b)=\sum(y_i - b_0 - \sum_jx_{ij}b_j)^2.$

You rewrite this as:

$RSS(b) = (y-Xb)^T(y-Xb)$

which has solution

$b = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = Ay$

which is the linear programming problem you mentioned, where the matrix $A$ is ill conditioned.

When you switch to lasso, the problem becomes:

$RSS(b) = (y-Xb)^T(y-Xb) + \lambda b$

This would end up being:

$b = (X^TX)(2X^Ty + \lambda)$

which simply CANT be written in a $Ay = b$ form, so it's impossible to see how the original matrix $A$ affects the problem.

The fact that $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is ill conditioned has no impact on the LASSO problem, as it simply solves a different problem which is quadratic! (and matrix ill conditioning is only defined for linear systems)